# How to get to values of given date in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, nsdate

I need to write a function, which get a date like this :  **"2017-04-20T12:12:17.004+0200"**

I found that this match pattern: **"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"**

And function return string: "It is Monday 20, May, year 2017".
To do this, I have to get to each value and validate them. I don't know how to do this. I know that there is something like **components**, but it used only with current date, not given. Could somebody help me?
Here's my code:

```
var date = "2017-04-20T12:12:17.004+0200"

let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: date) as? Date {
        print(date)
    } else {
        // invalid format
        print("bad format")
    }
```

Please help :(

Comment: FYI - you do not need the `as? Date` on the `if let` statement.

Comment: Once you get the `(NS)Date` object, change the `dateFormat` to something like "EEEE dd', year' yyyy", and use your dateFormatter to transform that `(NS)Date` into String: `dateFormatterGet.string(from:date)` (or something similar.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, I deleted it.

Comment: @Larme umm, it't not actually what I want

Comment: @Mark It seems most people believe that *is* what you want. If not, please clarify your question showing the real, actual results that you want.

Comment: @Mark " umm, it't not actually what I want " What do you want exactly that my comment doesn't suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with components, but this is not needed as you can just use the DateFormatter.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'It is' EEEE dd, MMMM, 'year' yyyy"
    // Just for this example we set it English
    // a better solution would be to use the devices local,
    // since this is what the user expecting how the date should be presented. 
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
    let formatted = dateFormatter.string(from: date);

    print(formatted)
} else {
    // invalid format
    print("bad format")
}
```

I added an locale to the dateformatter to make sure the format is in English.

Comment: FYI - the format could be: `"'It is' EEEE dd, MMMM, 'year' yyyy"`. You only need to quote letters, not any punctuation. Makes it ever so slightly easier to read.

Comment: Also, you should set the `locale` of the formatter to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` before trying to convert the ISO8601/RFC3339 date string to a `Date` object. But go ahead and convert it back to `.current`, or whatever, when creating the final string from the `Date` object.

Comment: @Rob what issues could there be in this date string that would be solved by `en_US_POSIX `? Since there is not localised date in there or am I missing something?

Comment: @rckoenes - The original date string is not a localized date string, which is precisely why you have to use `en_US_POSIX`. If the user's calendar isn't Gregorian, you have no assurances that the numeric values in the Gregorian ISO8601 date can be parsed correctly. Also, even if it doesn't choke, the `Date` object won't represent the same date as the original date string. And, FYI, I think that the final date string should be localized (e.g. if the user and device is using a non-Gregorian calendar, they're going to consider it a bug if it shows dates in Gregorian format).

Comment: @rob thanks fro the explanation, I'm well aware of the issue that you should the device local. Since you never know how the user want the date to be displayed, but then more issues come to play, like should it be `Monday 20` or `20 monday`.

Comment: Agreed. I'd personally use `formatter.dateStyle = .full` (or if I wanted to pick which elements to include, perhaps some variation of `formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEEdMMMMyyyy"‌​)`) rather than the OPs very curious format.